# Android SQLite - Store image in database

Tags: android, sqlite, blob, android-bitmap

I am trying to store images to a table that I am creating in my android application. The table has eight columns (int id, String name, String summary, String imdb, String poster1Url, Bitmap poster1, String poster2Url, Bitmap poster2).

This is my Table code:

```
public class Favorite {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";

        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        public static final String COLUMN_SUMMARY = "summary";
        public static final String COLUMN_IMDB = "imdb";
        public static final String COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM_URL = "posterMediumUrl";
        public static final String COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM = "posterMedium";
        public static final String COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL_URL = "posterOriginalUrl";
        public static final String COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL = "posterOriginal";

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String summary;
        private String imdb;
        private String posterMediumUrl;
        private Bitmap posterMedium;
        private String posterOriginalUrl;
        private Bitmap posterOriginal;


        // Create table SQL query
        public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                        + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
                        + COLUMN_SUMMARY + " TEXT,"
                        + COLUMN_IMDB + " TEXT,"
                        + COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM_URL + " TEXT,"
                        + COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM + " blob,"
                        + COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL_URL + " TEXT,"
                        + COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL + " blob"
                        + ")";

        public Favorite() {
        }

    public Favorite(int id, String name, String summary, String imdb, String posterMediumUrl, Bitmap posterMedium, String posterOriginalUrl, Bitmap posterOriginal) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.imdb = imdb;
        this.posterMediumUrl = posterMediumUrl;
        this.posterMedium = posterMedium;
        this.posterOriginalUrl = posterOriginalUrl;
        this.posterOriginal = posterOriginal;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getImdb() {
        return imdb;
    }

    public void setImdb(String imdb) {
        this.imdb = imdb;
    }

    public String getPosterMediumUrl() {
        return posterMediumUrl;
    }

    public void setPosterMediumUrl(String posterMediumUrl) {
        this.posterMediumUrl = posterMediumUrl;
    }

    public Bitmap getPosterMedium() {
        return posterMedium;
    }

    public void setPosterMedium(Bitmap posterMedium) {
        this.posterMedium = posterMedium;
    }

    public String getPosterOriginalUrl() {
        return posterOriginalUrl;
    }

    public void setPosterOriginalUrl(String posterOriginalUrl) {
        this.posterOriginalUrl = posterOriginalUrl;
    }

    public Bitmap getPosterOriginal() {
        return posterOriginal;
    }

    public void setPosterOriginal(Bitmap posterOriginal) {
        this.posterOriginal = posterOriginal;
    }
}
```

This is my DataBaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "favorites_db";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // create favorites table
        db.execSQL(Favorite.CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Favorite.TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long insertFavorite(Favorite favorite) {
        // get writable database as we want to write data
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Favorite.COLUMN_ID, favorite.getId());
        values.put(Favorite.COLUMN_NAME, favorite.getName());
        values.put(Favorite.COLUMN_SUMMARY, favorite.getSummary());
        values.put(Favorite.COLUMN_IMDB, favorite.getImdb());
        values.put(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM_URL, favorite.getPosterMediumUrl());
        values.put(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM, Utility.getPictureByteOfArray(favorite.getPosterMedium()));
        values.put(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL_URL, favorite.getPosterOriginalUrl());
        values.put(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL, Utility.getPictureByteOfArray(favorite.getPosterOriginal()));

        // insert row
        long id = db.insert(Favorite.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        // close db connection
        db.close();

        // return newly inserted row id
        return id;
    }

    public Favorite getFavorite(long id) {
        // get readable database as we are not inserting anything
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Favorite.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Favorite.COLUMN_ID, Favorite.COLUMN_NAME, Favorite.COLUMN_SUMMARY, Favorite.COLUMN_IMDB, Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM_URL, Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM, Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL_URL, Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL},
                Favorite.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        Favorite favorite = null;

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // prepare favorite object
            favorite = new Favorite(
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_ID)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_NAME)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_SUMMARY)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_IMDB)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM_URL)),
                    //null,
                    Utility.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM))),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL_URL)),
                    Utility.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL))));
                    //null);
            // close the db connection
            cursor.close();
        }
        return favorite;
    }

    public List<Favorite> getAllFavorites() {
        List<Favorite> favorites = new ArrayList<>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Favorite.TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Favorite favorite = new Favorite();
                favorite.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_ID)));
                favorite.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_NAME)));
                favorite.setSummary(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_SUMMARY)));
                favorite.setImdb(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_IMDB)));
                favorite.setPosterMediumUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_MEDIUM_URL)));
                favorite.setPosterMedium(Utility.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_NAME))));
                favorite.setPosterOriginalUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_POSTER_ORIGINAL_URL)));
                favorite.setPosterOriginal(Utility.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Favorite.COLUMN_NAME))));

                favorites.add(favorite);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // close db connection
        db.close();

        // return favorites list
        return favorites;
    }

    public int getFavoritesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Favorite.TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();


        // return count
        return count;
    }

    public void deleteFavorites(Favorite favorite) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Favorite.TABLE_NAME, Favorite.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(favorite.getId())});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

In my Adapter I call this AsyncTask to get the image from the URL, convert to Bitmap and insert into my table:

```
public class SaveIntoDatabase extends AsyncTask<Favorite,Void,Void> {
        // can use UI thread here
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Favorite... params) {
            Favorite favorite = params[0];
            System.out.println("Inicio");
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new URL(favorite.getPosterMediumUrl()).openStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                //set bitmap value to Picture
                favorite.setPosterMedium(bitmap);
                System.out.println(bitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new URL(favorite.getPosterOriginalUrl()).openStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                //set bitmap value to Picture
                favorite.setPosterOriginal(bitmap);
                System.out.println(bitmap);
                //add data to database
                db.insertFavorite(favorite);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Fim");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And I call that Async task using this code:

```
TvShow tvShow = tvShowList.get(position);
                    SaveIntoDatabase task = new SaveIntoDatabase();
                    task.execute(new Favorite(Integer.parseInt(tvShow.getId()), tvShow.getName(), tvShow.getSummary(), tvShow.getTvShowExternals().getImdb(), tvShow.getTvShowImage().getMedium(), null, tvShow.getTvShowImage().getOriginal(), null));
```

This is how I convert a blob to a Bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromByte(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
```

This is how I convert a Bitmap to a blob:

```
public static byte[] getPictureByteOfArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Everything seems fine to me but when I try to access the pictures inside the results from my table I get "null" from both of the pictures.

Comment: No exceptions in logcat?

Comment: The only thing that says is: W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.example.mvaguimaraes.avenuecodetest/databases/favorites_db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

But I get neither errors nor exceptions in the logcat. Only null Bitmaps.